# Linting imports or de-structured variables onto separate lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

We are looking to implement a linting rule which will catch any imports or destructured variables to make them display on different lines.

e.g.

```
// bad (ok, so not so much bad as not what we want)
import { Component1, Component2, Component3 } from 'some-library';

const { variable1, variable2, variable3 } = structuredVariable;

// good (or preferred format)
import {
  Component1,
  Component2,
  Component3,
} from 'some-library';

const {
  variable1,
  variable2,
  variable3,
} = structuredVariable;
```

Is this possible through es-lint/any other method?

Comment: you can write your own es-lint plugin if nothing else

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9259

Comment: nice find @Bergi!  I looked through the issues and must have missed this one somehow